# Android Naviagtion Items not Displaying Fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have created a **navHost** which i would like to replace with fragments from the my **navGraph** and using the **onNavigationItemSelected** event listener i want the navHost replaced by every navigation item i have selected. But i still dont know why the **FragmentTransaction.replace** method doesnt get the navHost replaced by the navGraph commited to

**content_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"></fragment>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**mobile_navigation.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:name="com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_manager"
        android:name="com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.manager.AccountManagerFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account_manager" />

    <fragment
         android:id="@+id/nav_atc"
         android:name="com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.atc.AtcFragment"
         android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_atc" />


     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/nav_buy_airtime"
         android:name="com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.buy_airtime.BuyAirtimeFragment"
         android:label="@string/menu_tools"
         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_buy_airtime" />

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/nav_send_money"
         android:name="com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.send_money.SendMoneyFragment"
         android:label="@string/menu_share"
         tools:layout="@layout/fragment_send_money" />

</navigation>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.airtimeflip;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.airtimeflip.config.GlobalUtilConfig;
import com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.atc.AtcFragment;
import com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.buy_airtime.BuyAirtimeFragment;
import com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.home.HomeFragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.manager.AccountManagerFragment;
import com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.profile.ProfileFragment;
import com.example.airtimeflip.ui.fragments.send_money.SendMoneyFragment;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
//    private NavigationView navigationView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //adding event listener to the navigation view
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_manager,
                R.id.nav_atc, R.id.nav_buy_airtime, R.id.nav_send_money)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
       NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        int id = menuItem.getItemId();
        menuItem.setChecked(true);

        try {
            if (id == R.id.nav_home){
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new HomeFragment());
                ft.commit();
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_atc){
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new AtcFragment());
                ft.commit();
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_buy_airtime){
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new BuyAirtimeFragment());
                ft.commit();
            }else if (id == R.id.nav_profile){
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new ProfileFragment());
                ft.commit();
            }else if (id == R.id.nav_manager){
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new AccountManagerFragment());
                ft.commit();
            }else if (id == R.id.nav_send_money){
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new SendMoneyFragment());
                ft.commit();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: "+ e.toString());
        }

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think onNavigationItemSelected is not getting triggered when using appBarConfiguration. Just check by removing it.

Comment: Appbar gets distorted after removing

Comment: Yes, Need to figure out.

Comment: great! am on it

Comment: OK, i have got things back on but still, onNavigationItemSelected  is not working. what do you think could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Something you are doing wrong here. You are using wrong id.
 `R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_atc, R.id.nav_buy_airtime ,R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_manager, R.id.nav_send_money`. These all are navigation fragment id. But instead you should use menu id.

Also When using Navigation, Navigate to destination using NavController.
Replace this code, this code will also work but the navigation architecture comes with more convenient way of doing the things.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new HomeFragment());
            ft.commit();
```

with this

```
navController.navigate(R.id.nav_atc);
```

Also this lines are redundant

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); // No need use the same which you have initialize in onCreate
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
```

Just use

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
```

Comment: i changed the fragment in the content_main.xml to FramemLayout and its working. i dont know why but its working